# How can I get BSE stock quote value in PHP?

Tags: php, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I want to get BSE stock quote value in PHP. I was trying Yahoo Finance API code. First 7 days it was fine, getting all values properly, but after few days it responses Null value. It's not only in my code - also problem in yahoo YQL. Please let me know how can I overcome this problem.

My code is:

```
$LastTradePriceOnly="";
$quoto="";
$Change="";
$percentage="";
$status="";
$raw="";
$ret_xml="";

$BASE_URL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

$query = 'select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22LINCPENQ.BO%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';

$yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" .$query;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$yql_query_url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);     
$raw = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as you said, there's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: You should pass the query with `baseurl encode` format

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=LINCPENQ.BO there is no data besides for price and you do not ask for that in your query.
if you look at http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=GOOG you will see lots of data. if you put goog in your code it works.

Comment: But data does not return in BSE registered company. why ?

Answer (score 0):

see the moneycontrol site they publish BSE and NSE stock updates.
use php dom function to collect these information and save all into your database.